# Getting values out of dictionaries which have arrays as values

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary which contains languages as values and the initial character of every language name (A, B, C, ...) as for the key.

```
var dictionary = [Character: [Language]]()
```

I would like to get all the languages out of the dictionary in the form of an array. To do so, I do

```
let languages = dictionary.values // Dictionary<Character, [Language]>.Values
```

That's not an array. I try to get the array like this

```
let languages = Array(tableViewSource.values) // [[Language]]
```

This returns an array of an array. How do I just get an array of languages? I saw the [`merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892855-merge) but I don't need to merge dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let allLangs = nestedArr.reduce([], +)
```

Comment: *If* you want to use `reduce` then it would be better to use `reduce(into:...)` to avoid the creation of intermediate arrays.

Comment: `reduce(into: [], +=)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single array (concatenating all dictionary values) then

```
Array(dictionary.values.joined())
```

does the trick. (This creates the final array without creating any additional intermediate arrays.)

Example:

```
let dictionary: [Character: [String]] = ["E": ["espanol", "english"], "G": ["german", "greek"]]
let langs = Array(dictionary.values.joined())
print(langs) // ["german", "greek", "espanol", "english"]
```

Note that the order of key/value pairs in a dictionary is unspecified.
An alternative is

```
let dictionary: [Character: [String]] = ["E": ["espanol", "english"], "G": ["german", "greek"]]
let langs = dictionary.keys.sorted().flatMap { dictionary[$0]! }
print(langs) // ["espanol", "english", "german", "greek"]
```

which gives the languages sorted by the corresponding keys.

Answer (score 1):

[Martin R's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890814/6272142) and [Sh_Khan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890753/6272142) answers outline the standard ways of doing this (you basically just want to flatten an array). However I'd like to show a more "manual" approach:

```
var langs = [String]()
for lang_list in dictionary.values {
    langs.append(contentsOf: lang_list)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `+=` operator instead of `.append(contentsOf:)`. An easier way of doing this would be using [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap):

```
dictionary.values.flatMap { $0 }
```